# Is it possible to search for some keywords inside LinkedIn groups?

Tags: linkedin, linkedin-groups

Is it possible to search for some keywords inside LinkedIn groups even if I have not joined them?

This may be simple, but I did not find a solution; I can only find group names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible by using the Advanced search. There you can write some keywords and the related Groups to look. But it is possible only for Groups that you have joined. I'm not aware if there are more possibilities for "Pro" accounts.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate? Perhaps with one or more screenshots.

Comment: There's nothing more to say actually! I'll try to add some screenshots though.

Comment: it looks like this Advanced search UI was deprecated in 2017 https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/advanced-search-gone-new-linkedin-interface-robert-knop/